# Regex in c# to find files in log

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find some filenames that are written into a logfile that end on 'K.TIF'.

I'm trying to find:

```
20130629VGM180ZZ001001K.TIF 
20130629VGM180ZZ001002K.TIF
```

etc.

As I'm terrible in regex's, I tried this:

```
Regex.Match(line, @"([A-Z0-9]+){23}\.TIF", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Regex.Match(line, @"(?<=\\)(.>)(?=K\.TIF){23}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

The first one is terrible, doesn't perform and gives bad results.

The second one actually gives all the TIF that end on Z.TIF if I change K\ to Z. However, it does not find any K.TIF's with the current regex.

Comment: If performance is a problem, use a static compiled Regex like so: `static Regex _matcher = new Regex(@".......", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled)` and in your check you simply do `_matcher.Match(line)`. Should be **a lot** faster. The first one should not have performance-problems.

Comment: Also, you should change `@"([A-Z0-9]+){23}\.TIF"` to `@"[a-z0-9\\]K\.TIF"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work for me:

```
^.*\\(\w*K.TIF)$
```

It searches for the last slash and then captures the word characters followed by `K.TIF`. Example: http://www.regex101.com/r/nH6gV4

Comment: Seams the easiest and fastest way. Thanks for the solution, works perfect for me!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
@"\w+K\.TIF$"
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex will get what you want:

```
\\([A-Z0-9]{22}K\.TIF)$
```

You shouldn't use `IgnoreCase` as you specifically made the regex to match just caps.

The extract value will be inside a match group so use:

```
string MatchedFileName = Regex.Match(line, @"[A-Z0-9]{22}K\.TIF$").Value;
```

(Updated, thanks Tyler for pointing out I hadn't read the OP's question properly)

(Updated again as it didnt need the backslash at the start or the capture group)

Comment: This will get all then end in .TIF not K.TIF

Answer (score 0):

The first regular expression is very close to the answer, but it has an extra '+'. I think you can try the following code.

```
Regex.Match(line, @"([A-Z0-9]){22}K\.TIF", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `var res = Regex.Match(line, @"(?im)^.+k\.tif$";`